# uwp project not able to build on Visual Studio 2017 15.8

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

Even a blanc **uwp** project is not able to build on visual studio 2017 **15.8**. Two minor versions have been released since **15.8.1** and **15.8.2** since than but they show the same problem.

**Behavior** : when you just try to restore nuget packages or build the project, the Build windows shows no output, i.e : it is black as if no progress is happening in build, and it remains like this for infinite amount of time, until you cancel the build, then it says "The Build has been canceled".

Comment: the same project I can build on my azure VM on a visual studio 2017 15.7.2

Comment: bug report was out there for 15.8.0 but it seems inconsistent bcz I just posted it on twitter and some people reported they cannot reproduce this on 15.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way is to trace your code to git and then you should close the VisualStudio and use git bash input the code.

```
git clean -xdf
```

This code can clean all of your temp files and then you can use VisualStudio to rebuild.

You can also use the new VisualStudio 2017 project to build your UWP code.

The new VisualStudio 2017 project is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` that can use nuget in your nuget folder and it needs do not copy nuget to the local folder.

See [How to: Reference an MSBuild Project SDK - Visual Studio | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2017)

[Old csproj to new csproj: Visual Studio 2017 upgrade guide](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with following steps:

1. delete **obj** and **bin** folders from the project.
2. Restart visual studio
3. Clean Solution.
4. Rebuild.